# Embedded resource mapping files added - class not mapped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In my asp.net mvc application I'm using nhibernate 3.2 as ORM. I have catalogue structure like
..\Models\Persons with User.cs and OtherClass.cs in it and also ..\Mapping with files hibernate.xml,Persons.xml I added mapping files as embeeded resources and in code of application I have

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
config.AddAssembly(assembly);
sFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I tried to run simple hql query

```
From User up WHERE up.Password=admin AND up.Login=admin
```

but I still get an error:

> A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException'  occurred in NHibernate.DLL
>   User is not mapped [ FROM User up WHERE up.Password=admin AND up.Login=admin]

I can't get an idea what I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the mappings are loaded by inspecting the sessionfactory properties after creation?

Comment: when try to check class with sessionfactory.GetClassMetadata() i get null everytime i check any class, seems embedding fails for it...but how to repair it?

Comment: ok found out with `config.AddInputStream()`, now everything works :)